# how to add font size property to style={{backgroundColor:"#41bedd"}}?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to give margin property in `style={{backgroundColor:"#41bedd"}}` but my page does not run? can anybody tell me how to use? I tried like this:

```
style={{backgroundColor:"#41bedd";margin:"10px"}}
```

It is not running though. Why?

Comment: Can you able to send full code

Comment: the separator should be comma, not semi-colon.

Comment: What are you using as front-end and back-end, @darshana?

Comment: <h3 className="color_dark fw_light m_bottom_15 heading_1" style={{backgroundColor:"#41bedd"}}>Who We Are ?</h3>

Comment: <h3 className="color_dark fw_light m_bottom_15 heading_1" style={{backgroundColor:"#41bedd"}}>Who We Are ?</h3>

Comment: @darshana please note [so] is a community of programmers helping each other grow professionally. It's mission statement is to ***make the web better***. It's not a programming school or tutorials website *per-se*. You are required to search and research before asking a question and you are also required to have the minimal required skill and knowledge necessary to understand the answers to your questions. In its current form, your question indicates you do not meet these requirements and that you have not even read [ask] in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

> **There is some syntax problem in your code. So try this for multiple attributes.**

```
style={{"backgroundColor" : "#41bedd", "margin" : "10px"}}
```